# Running Rabbit MQ from Source in Eclipse / Erlide

Tags: eclipse, erlang, rabbitmq, erlide

I've clone the RabbitMQ repository opened as an Erlang project in Eclipse using the erlide.org plugin.

I don't know how to run the application, and I have 249 errors.

Please can someone explain how to make it run?

EDIT - Example of some Errors

Description Location    Resource    Path    Type
can't find include file "rabbit_framing.hrl"    line 184    rabbit.erl  /home/nicktune/dev/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/rabbitmq-server/src/rabbit.erl  Erlang Problems

Description Location    Resource    Path    Type
function build_heartbeat_frame/0 undefined  line 30 rabbit_binary_generator.erl /home/nicktune/dev/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/rabbitmq-server/src/rabbit_binary_generator.erl Erlang Problems

Description Location    Resource    Path    Type
record 'basic.ack' undefined    line 1317   rabbit_tests.erl    /home/nicktune/dev/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/rabbitmq-server/src/rabbit_tests.erl    Erlang Problems

Comment: What are the first few errors you're getting?  (You can edit the question and put them there; that will get better formatting.)

Comment: Right, the include path is not getting set correctly for some reason. Someone who's more knowledgeable about Erlide should be able to tell how to fix it...

Comment: Hm, actually, `rabbit_framing.hrl` is an autogenerated file, so it's quite possible that it isn't getting generated by however Erlide is building the project.  Can you see `rabbit_framing.hrl` in the include directory?

Comment: No, it is not inside the include directory.

Comment: I think it might be because I didn't clone the codegen repository

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ comes with **Makefile** that can generate the **rabbit_framing.hrl** you are missing (with [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)). Just use **make** instead of erlide's compilation feature and you'll be fine.